# SQL Server 2005 Cube Query over Dimension with .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, mdx, cube

I would like to query over dimension data (.Net), and retrieve the info as table.
An example would be, have dimension `Customer`, with attributes `Name`, `Address`, `Street`, etc.

I want to have `Name`, `Address`, `Street` as columns, and the combinations between them in rows.

I found this query...

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Address]
  AS '[Customer].[Customer].Properties("Address")'

SELECT NON EMPTY {
   [Measures].[Address]
   } ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY [Customer].[Customer].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Customer Geography].[Australia]
```

But I don't have in advance neither properties nor hierarchy, I only have the dimension.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to specify attributes via DIMENSION PROPERTIES and access them as member attributes in the result. Then you can transform that result into table.

```
SELECT 
  [Customer].[Customer].ALLMEMBERS
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer].[Address]
   ,[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].[Education]
   ,[Customer].[Customer].[Customer].[Gender]
   ,PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,CHILDREN_CARDINALITY
   ,PARENT_LEVEL
   ,MEMBER_TYPE
   ON COLUMNS
 ,{} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Te result of that query is te memberas as Columns, but I need the properties as columns and their values as rows.

Comment: The properties are in the result. If you e. g. use Management Studio to run the MDX query and then double-click on a customer header cell, you will see the properties. How are you accessing the result from .NET? Are you using `ExecuteCellSet()`?